# The easiest way to write NSData to a file

Tags: file, cocoa, file-io, save

```
NSData *data;
data = [self fillInSomeStrangeBytes];
```

My question is now how I can write this `data` on the easiest way to an file.

(I've already an NSURL `file://localhost/Users/Coding/Library/Application%20Support/App/file.strangebytes`)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`NSData` has a method called `writeToURL:atomically:` that does exactly what you want to do. Look in [the documentation for `NSData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to see how to use it.

Comment: Does the source of the `NSData` object matter for this method?  [In this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150196/updating-sqlite-database-without-xml) I'm saving a .sqlite database I downloaded into a `NSData` object from a URL, but it doesn't seem to be saving it correctly.  The file is written, but when I try to access it (either through my app or with a 3rd party viewer) it tells me it's not a valid SQLite database.  Does `writeToURL:atomically:` only work for saving `NSString`s or something like that?

Comment: `NSData` is a wrapper for any kind of binary data. The original source shouldn't matter. Looking at your question, I'd recommend using `NSURLConnection` (or a library like `AFNetworking`) over `initWithContentsOfURL:`. For small downloads, `NSData` can be fine, but it doesn't provide any control over the download. When something goes wrong, this makes it hard to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 38):

Notice that writing `NSData` into a file is an IO operation that may block the main thread. Especially if the data object is large.

Therefore it is advised to perform this on a background thread, the easiest way would be to use GCD as follows:

```
// Use GCD's background queue
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // Generate the file path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfilename.dat"];

     // Save it into file system
    [data writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
});
```

Comment: how to retrieve it?

Comment: [`dataWithContentsOfFile:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1547226-datawithcontentsoffile?language=objc)

Answer (score 31):

[writeToURL:atomically:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIACAEJE) or [writeToFile:atomically:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIAEAHFJ) if you have a filename instead of a URL.

Comment: +1 for NSURL. NSURL pwns NSString when you point to a file. Apple always recommends NSURL for file paths rather than NSString. :)

Comment: I don't think there's a difference between writeToURL vs writeToFile. According to documentation: "Since at present only file:// URLs are supported, there is no difference between this method and writeToFile:atomically:, except for the type of the first argument"

Comment: Does the source of the `NSData` object matter for this method?  [In this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150196/updating-sqlite-database-without-xml) I'm saving a .sqlite database I downloaded into a `NSData` object from a URL, but it doesn't seem to be saving it correctly.  The file is written, but when I try to access it (either through my app or with a 3rd party viewer) it tells me it's not a valid SQLite database.  Does `writeToURL:atomically:` only work for saving `NSString`s or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

You also have [`writeToFile:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1414800-writetofile?language=objc) or [`writeToURL:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1410595-writetourl?language=objc) which can report error codes in case the saving of the `NSData` failed for any reason. For example:

```
NSError *error;

NSURL *folder = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:true error:&error];
if (!folder) {
    NSLog(@"%s: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);        // handle error however you would like
    return;
}

NSURL *fileURL = [folder URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
BOOL success = [data writeToURL:fileURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"%s: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);        // handle error however you would like
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if you want to do this a few times manually instead of coding, is to only use your mouse:

1. Put a breakpoint one line after your NSdata are fulfilled.

[image]

2. Hold your mouse over your NSData variable, click on the Eye button, and then export.
3. After that chose the storage details (name/extension/location of the file).

[image]

4. Click on "Save" and you are done!