# Swift: How to save data of different types in a file

Tags: ios, file, swift, server

I want to save data including string, number, date and coordinate in a file, and then transmit the file to a server. How to do this using swift?

And I'd like to process these data from the server in the future. What type of file is better to save them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am getting this right you can use [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/)

First you have to create a dictionary like this

```
    var dictionary = [String:AnyObject]()
            dictionary["age"] = 13
            dictionary["name"] = "Mike"
```

Then you have to transform this dictionary into NSData using nsjsonserialization

```
if let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options:NSJSONWritingOptions(0), error:nil) as NSData? {


                    request.HTTPBody = data

                }
```

But this is always depend on what the server is able to understand

Hope i helped. Sorry for my english

Comment: Thanks. But what I want to do is saving these data in a file, not transmitting them directly to the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679104/the-easiest-way-to-write-nsdata-to-a-file